# How do I access Firebase Firestore from Dart VM / Dart integration tests?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing a Flutter app that has fairly complex logic over the Firebase Firestore documents.
I am trying to write unit tests using `flutter_test` that actually execute this logic against the database (I know this is technically an integration test). This is because this logic has a lot of edge-cases I can only be sure are working if tested against the real database.

This seems to be an impossible task.

1. The [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) package can only run inside the phone because of how the authentication was implemented.
2. The [firebase](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase) package has 2 "implementations". One can only work on the browser, and the other one, the Dart VM one, which is a low level wrapper around the REST API, is almost completely undocumented.

The 2. [firebase](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase)  package for Dart VM has this example:

```
import 'package:firebase/firebase_io.dart';

void main() {
  var credential = ... // Retrieve auth credential
  var fbClient = new FirebaseClient(credential); // FirebaseClient.anonymous() is also available

  var path = ... // Full path to your database location with .json appended

  // GET
  var response = await fbClient.get(path);

  // DELETE
  await fbClient.delete(path);

  ...
}
```

... however it does not show how to get the `credential`. The [googleapis](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis) package shows how to get the `credentials`:

```
final _credentials = new ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(r'''
{
  "private_key_id": ...,
  "private_key": ...,
  "client_email": ...,
  "client_id": ...,
  "type": "service_account"
}
''');
```

... however this object is not a string and it is not written anywhere how to transform this into what the `FirebaseClient` class expects (`toString()` does not work). There is a [Github issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-dart/issues/314) on the firebase package on how to get this credentials but it is still unanswered.

I find it hard to believe that there is no information available online, that I could find, on how to write proper integration tests for Firebase Firestore.

Considerations:

- I have no interest mocking Firestore because my logic is complex and I want to test each edge-case against the real database.
- I have no interest using `Flutter Driver` because the tests are installed like normal apps in the phone and that takes time during development and it is not as straight-forward to debug as regular unit tests. Android Studio has very good test debug tools.

How should I write integration tests that access Firebase Firestore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For others who were brought here, as I was a few hours ago, by a search for ways to create that mysterious `credential` object when using the dart VM with Firebase, the following is my solution which works for accessing Firestore, at least.

The work is done by the Credentials class: (implemented below)

```
import 'package:firebase/firebase_io.dart';

String credential = await Credentials.fetch();
FirebaseClient fbClient = new FirebaseClient(credential);
```

The Credentials class creates the credential, using data from the Firebase Service Account private key (Firebase Console > [Project] > Settings > Project Settings > Service Accounts, then download the private key).

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import "package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart";
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Credentials {

  /// Returns a credential string to be used in the constructor
  /// of [FirebaseClient].
  static Future<String> fetch() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> pk = await getPrivateKey();
    // Fields from Firebase private key
    var accountCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson({
      "private_key_id": pk['private_key_id'],
      "private_key": pk['private_key'],
      "client_email": pk['client_email'],
      "client_id": pk['client_id'],
      "type": "service_account",
    });

    // Define the required scopes.
    // see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#working_with_google_identity_oauth_20_tokens
    var scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore",
    ];

    var client = new http.Client();
    AccessCredentials credentials =
        await obtainAccessCredentialsViaServiceAccount(
            accountCredentials, scopes, client);
    client.close();
    return credentials.accessToken.data;
  }

  static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getPrivateKey() async {
    String jsonString =
        await File('/Path/to/firebase_private_key/keyfile.json')
            .readAsString();
    return json.decode(jsonString);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I edited your answer to add some missing imports

Comment: Hi do you know how you would continue from to create a listener to collection changes?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the scope below allowed me to access firebase realtime

```
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
```

According to https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes it says that that scope is allowed to 'View your email address'.  This doesn't seem quite right but it made it work.

*(if anyone can help me understand this please add to the answer).*